# Unselect list item when another list item is clicked

Tags: javascript, html-lists, listitem

I would like to be able to unselect a list item when another list item is clicked, at the same time I would like to be able to select multiple list items in the same way that the select tag works, i.e. click and hold over multiple list items as well as shift clicking.

At the moment, I've got it set up so that I can select a list item and change the attribute value and background colour.

Javascript:

```
function selectLi(el)
{
  if ($(el).css( "background-color" )=="rgb(204, 204, 204)")
  {
    $(el).css( "background-color", "white");
    $(el).attr('selected',false);
  } 
  else 
  {
    $(el).css("background-color", "#ccc");
    $(el).attr('selected',true);
  }
}
```

My list items are being generated automatically:

```
$('#unorderedRight').append('<li value="' + $(this).val() + '" onclick="selectLi(this)" selected=false><input type="checkbox" id="'+ $(this).text()+'_checkbox">'+$(this).text()+'</li>');
```

At the moment if one list item is selected, and the user selects another list item, the first selected list item is not unselected (as is expected with this code). I'm unsure where to start with this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to loop over all elements in the unordered list where their selected attribute = selected and also check to make sure that the element you're currently looking at is not the same as the element you just clicked.

```
function selectLi(el)
    {
      console.log("addtoright");
      if ($(el).css( "background-color" )=="rgb(204, 204, 204)"){
        $(el).css( "background-color", "white");
        $(el).attr('selected',false);
      } 
      else {
        $(el).css("background-color", "#ccc");
        $(el).attr('selected',true);
        $("#unorderedRight li").each(function(i, obj)
        {
          if($(obj).attr('selected') == 'selected' && obj !== el)
          {
          $(obj).attr('selected', false);
          $(obj).css( "background-color", "white");
          }
        });
      }
    }
```